# Pandas maximum length of object type with None values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I’ve written a short function to output the maximum values (or for strings, maximum length) for each column in a data frame, with adjustments for various data types.

```
def maxDFVals(df):
    for c in df:
        if str(df[c].dtype) in ('datetime64[ns]'):
            print('Max datetime of column {}: {}\n'.format(c,  df[c].max()))
        elif str(df[c].dtype) in ('object', 'string_', 'unicode_'):
            df[c].fillna(value='', inplace=True)
            print('Max length of column {}: {}\n'.format(c, df[c].map(len).max()))
        elif str(df[c].dtype) in ('int64', 'float64'):
            print('Max value of column {}: {}\n'.format(c,  df[c].max()))
        else:
            print('Unknown data type for column {}!\n'.format(c))
```

It works fine, but I just wanted to check whether there is a better alternative to line 6, using fillna, which I needed in order to deal with None values.  Ideally I would just ignore None, but I couldn’t discover a way of using something like skipna=True.

If I really wanted to I guess I could add

```
           df[c].replace([''], [None], inplace=True)
```

after line 7 to return the None values, but that is hardly what anyone would call Pythonic…

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: can't you try this df[c].dropna().map(len).max()

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot @RakeshKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:-

```
def maxDFVals(df):
    for c in df:
        if str(df[c].dtype) in ('datetime64[ns]'):
            print('Max datetime of column {}: {}\n'.format(c,  df[c].max()))
        elif str(df[c].dtype) in ('object', 'string_', 'unicode_'):
            print('Max length of column {}: {}\n'.format(c, df[c].dropna().map(len).max()))
        elif str(df[c].dtype) in ('int64', 'float64'):
            print('Max value of column {}: {}\n'.format(c,  df[c].max()))
        else:
            print('Unknown data type for column {}!\n'.format(c))
```

Comment: Yes this works a treat.  Have used dropna before but it had totally slipped my mind.  Many thanks.